# Loading a user generated format from a library

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a user-generated format, save it to a library, and then use that format. For some reason when I save the format to the library it doesn't seem to work when I try to use it in a proc print statement later on.

Whenever I run this code it doesn't throw an error but the printed output for varName is not formatted in the way that I defined.

```html
libname fmtLib '/FILEPATH1';

DATA formatData;
 INFILE '/FILEPATH2' dsd;
 retain fmtname '$fname';
 Input start $ label $; 
run;

PROC format cntlin= formatData library fmtLib;
run;

proc print data = dataset (obs = 50);
 format varName $fname.;
run;
```

If I however use this code:

```html
libname fmtLib '/FILEPATH1';

DATA formatData;
 INFILE '/FILEPATH2' dsd;
 retain fmtname '$fname';
 Input start $ label $; 
run;

PROC format cntlin= formatData;
run;

proc print data = dataset (obs = 50);
 format varName $fname.;
run;
```

varName is formatted correctly. I'm not sure why having the format saved or not saved in a library would make the difference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your setting for the `FMTSEARCH` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you tell SAS where to find your new formats.  Use the `FMTSEARCH` option.

Let's make two different versions of the same format in two different format catalogs.

```
proc format lib=work.formcat1 ;
  value status 1='Good' 2='Bad' 3='Ugly';
run;

proc format lib=work.formcat2 ;
  value status 1='1 Good' 2='2 Bad' 3='3 Ugly';
run;
```

So if I just leave the FMTSEARCH option settings to the default and set `NOFMTERR` then if I print my sample data

```
options nofmterr ;
proc print data=test;
 title "%sysfunc(getoption(fmtsearch,keyword))";
 format status status. ;
run;
```

it doesn't find any `STATUS.` format so I see the raw values.

```
FMTSEARCH=(WORK LIBRARY)

Obs    status

 1       1
 2       2
 3       3
```

But if we set the FMTSEARCH to seach FORMCAT1 and then FORMCAT2 when we print using the new `STATUS.` format

```
options fmtsearch=(work.formcat1 work.formcat2);

proc print data=test;
 title "%sysfunc(getoption(fmtsearch,keyword))";
 format status status. ;
run;
```

it looks like this:

```
FMTSEARCH=(WORK.FORMCAT1 WORK.FORMCAT2)

Obs    status
 1      Good
 2      Bad
 3      Ugly
```

And if we reverse the search order then it finds the other version of the `STATUS.` format so the output looks like this.

```
FMTSEARCH=(WORK.FORMCAT2 WORK.FORMCAT1)

Obs    status
 1     1 Good
 2     2 Bad
 3     3 Ugly
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works in your second example is that you're loading the format into the WORK (or possibly USER, but likely WORK) library.  That's automatically part of your format search path.

Loading it into Work is fine, or you can use Tom's suggestion to define FMTSEARCH.  Mostly this depends on whether you are using this in repeated sessions or just doing this for the current session.